# How to Unfollow a Blog in Blogspot

Tags: blogger

You can follow any blogs that are hosted on [blogspot](http://www.blogger.com). But how do you unfollow a blog, if you accidentally follow one?

I tried [the suggestion](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=104226) here on unfollow a blog, but unfortunately the help seems outdated.

Comment: None of these above answers worked for me

Comment: this is the solution now - http://blogging.nitecruzr.net/2013/01/blog-readers-report-inability-to-remove.html

Comment: if this old question is referring to what is currently called "Blogger", it seems you can directly "Follow" but cannot unfollow without starting your own Blogger account. Therefore, to unfollow a blog, the steps are: (i) click on the 'Blogger' link; (ii) start your own account; (iii) click on "Reading List" in your Blogger account; (iv) click on "MANAGE" (v) delete the blog subscribed to. I just discovered this today via direct experience (which is how I found this Stack Exchange page with unhelpful answers for me).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the "Settings" link for the blog you want to stop following. A new window will pop up  asking you to sign on with either google or other options. Sign on by selecting google if you access blogspot through google. Enter your user ID and password. Your next screen you will see an option of "Stop following this site" link on the right side, near the middle of the page. After you click the link, you will need to confirm that you really want to stop following the blog.

Comment: Neither of these applies to the new blogger format. I've tried everything and nothing works. There's no longer a "manage" button at the top of the reading list. It's now an "add" button. Many of the blogs I followed in the past are no longer active and I'd like to trim the list down.

Comment: @user19055 Try [Google Friend Connect](http://www.google.com/friendconnect/user/overview)

Answer (score 3):

On your Dashboard page, click on the gearwheel icon on the upper right of your Reading List near "View in Google Reader". When the "Manage Blogs I'm Following" page opens up, click on the "Settings" link across from the title of the blog that you want to stop following. A box will open so that you can log into "Google Friend Connect."  Next, click on the "Settings" link again and a new window will open where you can click on the "Stop following this site" link. It will then ask you to confirm your choice or cancel it.

Comment: As FriendConnect has partially retired, the first part of this answer no longer works. You will have to go to [Google Friend Connect's Sites I've Joined](http://www.google.com/friendconnect/user/overview) page instead to unfollow blogs. From there, click Settings on each blog and you can Stop following this site, or you can go to Sites I've joined section in the pop-up and quickly unfollow a lot of blogs.